# Como usar un pipe en angular con varios select?

Tags: angular, select, pipe, ngfor

como puedo lograr usar un pipe en angular con varios select o mat-select. Product, es una lista de productos , pero tienen categorías , por ejemplo, calzados, zapatos , etc.

```
<select>
<option *ngFor="let item of product | filter:'calzados'" [value]="item.id" >
  {{item.name}}
</option>
</select>

<select>
<option *ngFor="let item of product | filter:'zapatos'" [value]="item.id">
  {{item.name}}
</option>
</select>
```

Tengo un pipe echo pero no me funciono, no me muestra por separado las categorías , solamente me muestra la primera que es calzado , no se que estoy haciendo mal.

```
let product= value.filter((category) => { 
  if(category.name.some('calzado')){ 
    return true

  }else if(category.name.some('zapatos')){ 
    return true
  })
  return product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo una estructura de datos como esta:

```
products = [
    {
      name : 'producto 1',
      category: 'zapatos'
    },
    {
      name : 'producto 2',
      category: 'zapatos'
    },
    {
      name : 'producto 3',
      category: 'calzados'
    },
    {
      name : 'producto 4',
      category: 'calzados'
    },
  ]
```

La lógica del `pipe` sería así:

```
transform(products: any[], category: string): any {
    return products.filter(p => p.category == category);
  }
```

Se recibe el arreglo `products` y se filtran aquellos en los que la categoría coincida.

[Ejemplo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1nbxze?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)